# Path Finding Maze-Error

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to implement the depth first algorithm to solve a maze, but the code i wrote somehow 
doesnt appear to do anything, neither raises a error nor the expected result, witch is "filling" the path
array with the visited coordenates, because when i print the path array i get an empty array.

```
public static boolean searchPath(char[][] maze, int x, int y, List<Integer> path) {

    if(maze[y][x]=='E') {
        path.add(x);
        path.add(y);
        return true;
    }
    if(maze[y][x]=='_') {

        int dx = -1;
        int dy = 0;
        if(x +dx >0 && y + dx > 0 && x + dx < maze.length && y + dx < maze[0].length && searchPath(maze,x+dx,y+dy,path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 1;
        dy = 0;
        if (x +dx >0 && y + dx > 0 && x + dx < maze.length && y + dx < maze[0].length && searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 0;
        dy = -1;
        if (x +dx >0 && y + dx > 0 && x + dx < maze.length && y + dx < maze[0].length &&  searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 0;
        dy = 1;
        if (x +dx >0 && y + dx > 0 && x + dx < maze.length && y + dx < maze[0].length && searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

here is where I call searchPath.

```
    public MazeReader() {

        setTitle("Maze");
        setSize(640,480);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DepthFirst.searchPath(Maze, 0, 1, path);
        pathIndex = path.size() - 2;

}
```

here is tha maze with which i am dealing:

```
_SW_____W
_WWW_W_WW
_____W_EW
```

I think the problem may lay on the fact that the previuos array where the maze is 
stored is not being imported correctly to the DepthFirst class. Any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off you never are checking for the start symbol so it fails right from the start. Add that to the line

```
 if(maze[y][x]=='_' || maze[y][x] == 'S') {
```

There are a bunch of problems in this next line

```
if (x +dx >0 && y + dx > 0 && x + dx < maze.length && y + dx < maze[0].length
```

It should be x+dx >=0 as its okay to be at 0. You are using x to check the nested array so it should be x + dx < maze[0].length && y + dy < maze.length. You add y + dx instead of y + dy several times.

Finally you need some way to avoid going back to the same coordinate multiple times. The way you have it results in stack overflow as the search will go back and forth between two coordinates forever. I added a boolean array called checked of the same size as the maze that is set to true when a coordinate has been checked to avoid returning to that point again.

Here it is all together.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    char[][] maze = {{'S', '_', '_'},{'W','W','E'}};
    boolean[][] checked = new boolean[2][3];
    searchPath(maze, 0, 0, l, checked);
    System.out.println(l.toString());
}

public static boolean searchPath(char[][] maze, int x, int y, List<Integer> path, boolean checked[][]) {

    if(checked[y][x]){
        return false;
    }
    checked[y][x] = true;

    if(maze[y][x]=='E') {
        path.add(x);
        path.add(y);
        return true;
    }
    if(maze[y][x]=='_' || maze[y][x] == 'S') {

        int dx = -1;
        int dy = 0;
        if(x +dx >=0 && y + dy >= 0 && x + dx < maze[0].length && y + dy < maze.length && searchPath(maze,x+dx,y+dy,path, checked)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 1;
        dy = 0;
        if(x +dx >=0 && y + dy >= 0 && x + dx < maze[0].length && y + dy < maze.length && searchPath(maze,x+dx,y+dy,path, checked)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 0;
        dy = -1;
        if(x +dx >=0 && y + dy >= 0 && x + dx < maze[0].length && y + dy < maze.length && searchPath(maze,x+dx,y+dy,path, checked)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 0;
        dy = 1;
        if(x +dx >=0 && y + dy >= 0 && x + dx < maze[0].length && y + dy < maze.length && searchPath(maze,x+dx,y+dy,path, checked)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what the last two lines of code do(path.add(y) and return true)?

Comment: Sorry they were just a copy paste error. I have removed them.